# How to add video player in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, video-player

I am using xamarin.form portable (cross platform) having android and IOS project.

I want to add video in xaml page. 
I refer to https://components.xamarin.com/view/video-player it is license version so I don't want to use it.

Please suggest me how to add video player.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following thread useful:-

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23931/android-video-player-using-xamarin-forms

Forms Native Video Player shows how to play a video from a url link in a Xamarin.Forms application. Screen rotation is enabled to allow full screen, but no other controls were built in to keep this a more basic example.

https://github.com/xamarin/customer-success-samples/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/FormsNativeVideoPlayer

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution on below link

https://github.com/amccorma/xamarin-amccorma/tree/master/VideoPlayer

work sucessfully